# How to select from dropdown and reflect on the url like this sample.com/past_questions/chemistry/?exam_div=gce&exam_year=2018

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:40px">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <p><strong><label> Examination Division</strong></label>
    </p>
    <div>
      <select type="text" name="exam_div" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom:15px;padding:0px 10px;font-size:16px;">
        <option value selected>Select exam division </option>
        <option value="https://sample.com/past-questions/chemistry/?&amp;exam_div=jamb">JAMB</option>
        <option value="https://sample.com/past-questions/chemistry/?&exam_div=gce"> GCE</option>
        <option value="https://sample.com/past-questions/chemistry/?&exam_div=alevel">A LEVEL</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <p><strong><label>Examination Year</strong></label>
    </p>
    <div>
      <select type="text" name="exam_div" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom:15px;padding:0px 10px;font-size:15.5px;">
        <option value selected>Select an exam year</option>
        <option value="https://sample.com/past-questions/chemistry/?&exam_year=2018">2018</option>
        <option value="https://sample.com/past-questions/chemistry/?&exam_year=2017">2017</option>
        <option value="https://sample.com/past-questions/chemistry/?&exam_year=2016">2016</option>
        <option value="https://sample.com/past-questions/chemistry/?&exam_year=2015">2015</option>
        <option value="https://sample.com/past-questions/chemistry/?&exam_year=2014">2014</option>
        <option value="https://sample.com/past-questions/chemistry/?&exam_year=2013">2013</option>
        <option value="https://sample.com/past-questions/chemistry/?&exam_year=2012">2012</option>
        <option value="https://sample.com/past-questions/chemistry/?&exam_year=2011">2011</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: yes, it is just a sample code. i am just looking for a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> combine the two drop downdowns into a single url that includes both the division and year

Keep it simple:

- put only the div/year values on the option value, not the whole url
- add the base url to a findable location with `data-`
- add events with jquery, not `onclick=`
- use `.on("change"...` on both the selects and check that both values have been entered
- combine all 3 (url+2x values) into a url and redirect (commented out below)

```js
$(".selection select").on("change", function() {
  var division = $("#exam_div").val();
  var year = $("#exam_year").val();
  if (division === "" || year === "")
    return;
  var url = $(".selection").data("url") + "?exam_div=" + division + "&exam_year=" + year;
  //location.href = url;
  console.log(url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='selection' data-url='https://sample.com/past-questions/chemistry'>
  <div>
    <p><strong>Examination Division</strong></p>
    <div>
      <select name="exam_div" id="exam_div">
        <option value selected>Select exam division </option>
        <option value="jamb">JAMB</option>
        <option value="gce"> GCE</option>
        <option value="alevel">A LEVEL</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p><strong>Examination Year</strong>
    </p>
    <div>
      <select name="exam_year" id="exam_year">
        <option value selected>Select an exam year</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
        <option value="2016">2016</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2012">2012</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

from a UX perspective, this would be better with the click of a "GO" button rather than select on change and the change event fires when changing select options with the keyboard.

Comment: i think i'm not getting it right, please check what is wrong. i expected the url to reload and publish the page but nothing move.

Comment: Did you uncomment the `location.href=` part?  In the answer code this is commented so that you don't get redirected out of SO

Comment: the select onchange event option does load after select either of them. kindly check, and thank you your assistance

Answer (score 0):

```
<select type="text" name="exam_div" id="examdiv" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom:15px;padding:0px 10px;font-size:15.5px;">
        <option value selected>Select an exam year</option>
        <option value="https://sample.com/past-questions/chemistry/?&exam_year=2018">2018</option>
        <option value="https://sample.com/past-questions/chemistry/?&exam_year=2017">2017</option>
        <option value="https://sample.com/past-questions/chemistry/?&exam_year=2016">2016</option>
        <option value="https://sample.com/past-questions/chemistry/?&exam_year=2015">2015</option>
        <option value="https://sample.com/past-questions/chemistry/?&exam_year=2014">2014</option>
        <option value="https://sample.com/past-questions/chemistry/?&exam_year=2013">2013</option>
        <option value="https://sample.com/past-questions/chemistry/?&exam_year=2012">2012</option>
        <option value="https://sample.com/past-questions/chemistry/?&exam_year=2011">2011</option>
      </select>
```

use jquery try this

```
$(document).on('click', '#examdiv', function(){ 
            window.location.replace($('this').val());   
        });
```

Comment: I don't see any element in either your code or the OP code that has the id `this` as you refer to here `$('#this')`

Comment: yes, i'm still very new in javascript, kindly enlighten me on what to do.

Comment: `$('#this').val()` -> `$(this).val()`

Comment: OP is (as far as one can tell from the lack of actual question) trying to combine the two drop downdowns into a single url that includes both the division and year - not just redirect to the selected url.

Comment: Absolutely, you understood my question perfectly.